# Date to milliseconds / milliseconds to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, milliseconds

I have a date in milliseconds. obtained with something like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM NOW())
```

How do I revert to a date again?

I've tried with:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM NOW()))
```

The above returns a date in 1970 ...

Comment: `extract(MILLISECONDS ...)` only returns the fractional seconds from your timestamp. You are looking for `extract(epoch ..)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: This is incorrect. I already posted the correct explanation from the manual. It is undefined what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thom apparently expects `extract(milliseconds)` to get a value that can then be converted back to the original value. The only way to do this is to use the `epoch` value.

Comment: I want exactly what @a_horse_with_no_name said. Convert a date to milliseconds and revert it later.

Comment: The JKS' answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: So do you have an epoch (which is the number of *seconds*, no milliseconds) or do you have a "date in milliseconds", which probably is supposed to mean "timestamp in milliseconds"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `extract(MILLISECONDS ...)` returns more than just the "fractional seconds".

Comment: Erwin Brandstetter, I want to convert a date to milliseconds (not seconds). Then I want to revert it back to a date.

Comment: And you are aware of the difference between [`date` and `timestamp` or `timestamptz`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html)? `now()` returns `timestamptz`, not a "date".

Answer (score 1):

EXTRACT doesn't get you date in milliseconds. 
I think that should work:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW()) * 1000;
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW()))
```

[Found here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/how-to-get-the-timestamp-column-in-only-milliseconds-from-postgresql)

Comment: what does it return them? i'm using postgresql. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS ...)` gets you ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)) ...

> The seconds field, including fractional parts, multiplied by 1000.
>   Note that this includes full seconds.

Just test with:

```
SELECT now(), EXTRACT(MILLISECONDS FROM NOW()) AS millisec;
```

The rest is [in the manual as well](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> epoch
>
> For `timestamp with time zone` values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (can be negative); for `date` and `timestamp`
>   values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time;
>   for `interval` values, the total number of seconds in the interval
>
> ```
> SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40.12-08');
> *Result: 982384720.12*
>
> SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '5 days 3 hours');
> *Result: 442800*
> ```
>
> Here is how you can convert an epoch value back to a time stamp:
>
> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 982384720.12 * INTERVAL '1 second';
> ```
>
> (The `to_timestamp` function encapsulates the above conversion.)